# Recording email alerts in activity history of an object

Tags: custom-object, process-builder, email-alert, activityhistory

I have a custom object called employees. It stores employee details including their email ids. I have a process builder set up which sends email alert to this email ids when ever a record is created or edited. I would like to have a record what email is sent out an when in Activity history of the custom object Employee.

I explored a link - https://medium.com/@brilligence/salesforce-recording-activity-history-on-workflow-email-alerts-8ae227fa8cee#.wqr7rgth5 which talks about a solution, but seems like it is possible with Leads or contacts only and not with custom objects. Is that true? If so , is there any other way to store the activity of email alert in history?

Comment: All the docs state Accounts, contacts, opportunities. You could always try it with a custom object. It uses the ID after all. Otherwise you could create an apex email service and process the emails yourself

Comment: I tried the approach mentioned in the link but I could not see any emails getting created in activity history. I created a template with ref to the id of the record. Not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: @Eric I have a process builder on this custom object - Employee which sends time based email alerts in 2,4,6,8 weeks. I wish to records whenever the email is sent out in activity history. I tried the approach given in the link but does'nt seem to work. Do you think if the solution in the link should have worked? Thanks

Comment: I got it right! I had to add the from address to "My Acceptable Email Addresses" in my setting -> my email to Salesforce option. It worked and I was able to create the email in activity history.

Comment: @Eric do you want to add the answer on it?

Comment: @DaveHumm daddies as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the docs state Accounts, contacts, opportunities. You could always try it with a custom object. It uses the ID after all. Otherwise you could create an apex email service and process the emails yourself